# Dynamics CRM: Export relationships

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

CRM Online 2014.

Through the Dynamics CRM UI, is it possible to import/export relationships in the same way it is possible to import/export entity data?

I have a custom geographic entity that has a N:N relationship with the territory entity.  I need to export the relationship data between these two entities for importing into a different environment.

I know I can do it programmatic ally but I was hoping to do it through the CRM UI.

Thanks in advance,

Richard

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible to do with the CRM UI, but there is a plugin for XrmToolbox:

[New XrmToolBox plugin : Import/Export NN relationships](http://mscrmtools.blogspot.com/2014/05/new-xrmtoolbox-plugin-importexport-nn.html)

Answer (score 0):

Whenever it's possible, create manual N:N relationships, because this allow you to customize the entity, export data, create new fields and a lot of stuff.

Offcourse, you may need javascripts o plug-in to tune up this entity but they are usually easy to make and the N:N manual has more potencial than the native one.

Export data from a N:N native it is not possible by the UI.

Hope this can help you.